# Why Is My Powerline Adapter Not Giving Me My Download Speed

Tags: download, speed, adapter, powerline-networking

I recently bought a powerline adapter, the TP-LINK TL-PA4010KIT AV500 Nano Powerline Adapter, to be exact. But can't get more than 2MBps while downloading anything, whether it be on Steam or just generally in Google Chrome's browser. Even when I'm not doing anything else that takes internet, I can only get 1.8MBps at the max. I know about cable noise and making sure they are on the same side of the breaker box, but I don't know much about anything like that so I don't know what to do here. Please give me some information and explain why this is happening.

Comment: why do you think it's due to the adapter? Do you have better speed before it?

Comment: Bad reviews on that product.

Comment: Those speed are typical of Powerline 1.0 devices

Comment: Make sure you download the latest firmware from TP-Link

Answer (score 0):

2 MBps, or about 16.8 Mbps is only a bit below typical for AV500 powerline adapters. 20 Mbps is pretty much what you would expect with them. AV2 adapters such as those marked AV1200 or AV2000 do much, much better, typically getting over 100 Mbps.

It's also possible you have some kind of unusual situation. For example, some older AFCI circuit breakers severely degrade powerline bandwidth.

Make sure the adapters are plugged directly into the wall. Do not connect them to an extension cord, surge supresser, or UPS if you can avoid it. It can also help to experiment with different outlets.

Comment: I have TP-Link 500 powerline adapters and I currently get 6MBps, which is noticeably slower than in my old house, which was 8 to 10 MBps.